# Oracle Database CPU Usage on AIX

Tags: oracle, performance, aix

I want to find the CPU process usage for all Oracle processes on an AIX box.

On Solaris I can do the following:

```
prstat -n 400 -c -s cpu -p 9013 1 1
PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP
9013 oracle   3463M 2928M sleep   53    0   0:00:35 0.9% oracle/2
Total: 1 processes, 2 lwps, load averages: 2.25, 2.32, 2.40
```

This basically reports the CPU usage for a given process ID (in this case 9013). Given a list of all Oracle PID’s I can use this command to get the CPU usage for each one, sum them up and hey presto I have my Oracle database CPU usage.

How can I get the same with AIX?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect  you're looking for the `ps` command.

Comment: Hi there, the problem with the ps command is that it gives you the average utilisation since process startup time....certainly ps aux does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try nmon or topas, which will show the current %CPU.  You might also want to look into using WLM to create a class for all the Oracle processes, then use wlmstat to see the CPU usage for that class.  That would save you the trouble of adding them up manually.